# Buttons won't appear in Fyne GUI

Tags: go, user-interface, button, fyne

I created a window in fyne and it is supposed to show buttons I also created, but none end up showing up, even though I initialized them.  I am not sure what my error is.

```
a := app.New()
//fmt.Println("testing window location", &w)
w = a.NewWindow("Recursive Noise")
//fmt.Println("testing window location after new called", &w)

zoomIn := widget.NewButton("+", func() { zoomIn() })
//fmt.Println("print button", zoomIn)

zoomBox := widget.NewLabel("zoomFactor")
zoomOut := widget.NewButton("-", func() { zoomOut() })
//log.Println("tapped")

w.SetContent(zoomIn)
w.SetContent(zoomBox)
w.SetContent(zoomOut)
w.SetContent(widget.NewLabel("Recursive Noise"))
w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(512, 512))
```

[image: Image of GUI]

Comment: did you try to create a container? and set zoom in /box/out inside it? then you call w.SetContent(container). Method is fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewVBoxLayout(),in,box,out,etc)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the content of the window to lots of different things. Only one item can be at the content level of the window. To add may items put them in a container.
https://developer.fyne.io/explore/container

Comment: I used a particular layout.  How do I dynamically add a new element, like an image, to my layout? Beyond just container.New....() parameters

Comment: Container.Add()